# How:Click Button_Save And Open the wait Form until the process is complete In Form

Tags: vb.net

I have **two forms**

- **Form1** (Save Record)
- **Form2** (Wait Form )

1-**Press Button1 In Form1**

2-**open Form2 (Wait Form)**

3-**If Save(Button1 In Form1) has finished Then Close Form2(Form Wait)**

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Form2.ShowDialog()

    For aloop As Integer = 0 To 1000000

        Application.DoEvents()

        Label1.Text = Now

    Next

    Form2.Close()

End Sub
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qufqb.jpg)

Comment: Just put `Form2.Close` when the saving code finishes.

Comment: The problem is that the save is not done until the wait Form is closed

Comment: So the the saving code is in the `load_event` of `Form2`?

Comment: no ; In Form 1.

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right because you'er using `.ShowDialog()`, but there is a workaround this.

Comment: Try to use .Show() instead of .ShowDialog()

Comment: Definitely the problem here

Comment: I want to use (ShowDialog()) Only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Form2.ShowDialog()`, do this method, they have the same effect:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Form2.Show()
    Me.Enable = False

    For aloop As Integer = 0 To 1000000
        Application.DoEvents()
        Label1.Text = Now
    Next

    Form2.Close()
    Me.Enable = True
End Sub
```

So like this, Form1 will be disabled until the saving is done and Form2 closes, exactly like what will happen if `.ShowDialog()` worked.

**Hope that helped you :)**

Comment: Yes, Mose brother, this is the solution, I wish you success and your country Syria security and prosperity

Comment: Using `Application.DoEvents()` is _**bad practice**_ and therefore should not be used. I know that it's originally the OP's code, but it's worth knowing and it's one of those things that answers should address. For more information please see: [**Keeping your UI responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/)

Answer (score 2):

You ***SHOULD NOT*** use `Application.DoEvents()` to keep the UI responsive! ***EVER!*** Doing so is ***very bad practice!***

Please read: [**Keeping your UI responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/)

Instead you should be using multithreading (which has already been suggested, I know - but yet not without using `Application.DoEvents()`). The thread will need to do two things: Run the save code and close `Form2` when it's finished.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form2.Show()
    Me.Enabled = False

    Dim t As New Thread(AddressOf SaveThread)
    t.IsBackground = True
    t.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub SaveThread()
    'Put your save code here and remove Thread.Sleep() below.

    Thread.Sleep(6000) 'Simulating delay, 6000 ms = 6 seconds.

    If Me.InvokeRequired = True Then
        Me.Invoke(New MethodInvoker(AddressOf CloseWaitingForm))
    Else
        CloseWaitingForm()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CloseWaitingForm()
    Form2.Close()
    Me.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

And it's as simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want the user to interact with `Form1` while it's being saved,right?
Well, instead of using `.ShowDialog()`, you can disable the form for sometime.

Look at this:

```
 Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    'show your "Wait" form
    Form3.Show()
    'disable the current form
    Me.Enabled = False

    'do your work
    For aloop As Integer = 0 To 100000

        Application.DoEvents()

        TextBox1.Text = Now
    Next
    'close the "wait" form once it's saved
    Form3.Close()

    'enable the current form
    Me.Enabled = True
    'set focus to the current form
    Me.Focus()

End Sub
```

I tried it for myself before posting here. The form was minimized itself without that `.Focus()` so I put it there. 
Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Worth to know is that using `Application.DoEvents()` is _**bad practice**_. It should not be used to keep the UI responsive, that's what multithreading is for. For more information please see: [**Keeping your UI responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/)

Comment: Maybe you should comment this on the main post rather than this answer because this answer helps only to solve the problem of closing the `form2`.

Comment: I already wrote an answer stating the same. I know that it's originally from the OP's code, but it's worth knowing for everyone and is actually one of the things that answers should address. `DoEvents()` is an old "hack" that has been around since the days of VB6. It should not be used and should never had been. Still people keep finding it on the internet somewhere...

Comment: But you are right: I could've rephrased my comment indicating that I knew that part came from the OP's code. The reason I posted this on all the answers was to inform, _**not**_ to say "you are wrong".

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is .ShowDialog() method because it stops executing following commands until it's closed.
Try using .Show() instead of .ShowDialog() and disable Form1 as other answers suggested.

If you still want to use .ShowDialog(), I suggest you use **Threading.Thread**

Here is what can be done in Form1

```
    Public Class Form1
    Public tr As Threading.Thread

    Private Sub yourMethod()
        For aloop As Integer = 0 To 1000000
            If Label1.InvokeRequired Then
                Label1.Invoke(Sub() Label1.Text = Now)
            Else
                Label1.Text = Now
            End If

        Next
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        tr = New Threading.Thread(Sub() yourMethod())
        tr.Start()
        Form2.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
End Class
```

In Form2:

```
Public Class Form2

    Private Sub Form2_Shown(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Shown
        Do While Form1.tr.IsAlive
            Application.DoEvents()
        Loop
        Me.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

The above code does the following:

1. When you click the Button1 in Form1 it will set the method you want to a Public Threading.Thread variable when can be accessed by Form2
2. The thread will run yourMethod() in background, so you will need to check InvokeRequired first before you do any edits to your UI
3. After the thread is started, Form2.ShowDialog() command will be executed.
4. When the Form2 is initialized and shown, it will check if the thread is alive or not to determine to wait or close.

Comment: While it is good that you suggested multithreading you still haven't eliminated the DoEvents problem. One should _**NEVER**_ use `Application.DoEvents()` to keep the UI responsive.Closing the form in the end of the thread instead would've gotten the job done. Please see: [**Keeping your UI responsive and the Dangers of Application.DoEvents**](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jfoscoding/2005/08/06/keeping-your-ui-responsive-and-the-dangers-of-application-doevents/)